# How can I display thumb label all the time for material slider?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to let thumb label to display all the time no matter it is focused or not.
When I click on the slider it shows label like this.

[image]

But as soon as it is unfocused, the label is gone.

[image]

How can I get the label stay ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Angular `Material` doesn't provide this functionality by default, but you can handle this by adding following css in your global css file:

```
.mat-slider-thumb-label {
    transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 !important;
  }

.mat-slider-thumb {
    transform: scale(0) !important;
}

.mat-slider-thumb-label-text {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Working demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bkdwpj)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the slider value is 0 or if the slider is vertical and inverted

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work anymore with the new angular material version 15.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer didn't work consistently for me until I wrapped it in ng-deep

```
::ng-deep {
  .mat-slider-thumb-label {
    transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 !important;
  }  
  .mat-slider-thumb {
    transform: scale(0) !important;
  }  
  .mat-slider-thumb-label-text {
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }
}
```

This solution came from [willshowell](https://github.com/willshowell) here:  https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4803

Comment: If you place the suggested styles in your custom-theme.scss, or in styles.css then it will work. If you use ::ng-deep, then you'll want to use it with host like this   :host ::ng-deep { ... otherwise those styles could bleed.

Answer (score 5):

mdc based slider in Angular Material V15

```
::ng-deep .mdc-slider .mdc-slider__value-indicator {
  transform: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
.mdc-slider .mdc-slider__value-indicator {
  transform: none !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```