# How do we display slider thumb label always in angular 16 material

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

[How can I display thumb label all the time for material slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58057900/how-can-i-display-thumb-label-all-the-time-for-material-slider)

above answer is not working on angular 16 material ui slider.

Can you please provide the solution for this.

Comment: please provide stackblitz with the issue and package versions set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like on a slider with `[discrete]="true"` the label container is always displayed, but it's contents are transformed using `transform: scale(0)`, so it's not visible.

You should be able to override it easily by applying the proper transform to the proper element:

```
.mdc-slider .mdc-slider__value-indicator {
    transform: scale(1);
 }
```

Note that this style needs to have higher specificity than in the original material stylesheets, so you probably have to add a class to your slider, e.g.:

```
<mat-slider
    class="always-on-indicator"
    ...
</mat-slider>
```

And then apply changes only to elements of that class:

```
.always-on-indicator {
  &.mdc-slider .mdc-slider__value-indicator {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Remember to put either put this in the global styles.scss, or enable style piercing.

Here's [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/waqj3g).

Comment: It is working with by adding 
.mdc-slider .mdc-slider__value-indicator {
    transform: scale(1) !important;
 }